# Create XML file with .xml suffix in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a working XML file [here](http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/scrape.php?id=1). However, for a jQuery plugin I am using, it seems the file needs to actually end in .xml (rather than .php). I make this assumption because both [this](http://rollingstonesofficial.tumblr.com/rss) and [this](http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int) feed work with the plugin.

Might this be the solution? If so, how could I add the .xml suffix to my PHP-generated XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't caused by the missing `.xml` extension, other feeds also don't have this, it is caused by the invalid feed content. You can see the errors here: http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.comfyshoulderrest.com%2Fscrape.php%3Fid%3D1

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. By the way, my current header was header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8");

Comment: Omit the `charset=UTF8`

Comment: Afraid that doesn't do it either.

Comment: have you tried it? clear any caches before... (At the end there will be a way to add the .xml extension but I can't believe it is necessary. Which jQuery plugin you have in mind? )

Comment: Well, then in their example itself you can see they have used ` feed1: 'http://url/to/rss/feed'` which is not ending with .xml,
so it should support any url.

Comment: I can't see such restriction in the code. If it is not the header, then your feed xml itself isn't valid. (It also fails to render in browser)

Comment: It renders in my browser - is there a way of seeing if it's invalid? Some sort of error console?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I've just tried it with another XML feed that I made and it's working so there's some sort of error in the script, but it's not making itself immediately obvious...

Comment: Yes, nearly there! Is there a way of checking errors in the code?

Comment: Because you don't need to see the code to suggest using an error handler / console debugging / whatever is the norm for XML if any.